# Quotient with divisors of zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

Is there a ring $R$ with divisors of zero which have an ideal $I$ (non-null neither equal to $R$) that, the quotient $R/I$ also has divisors of zero?

Comment: Of course there is.  What examples have you looked at and why did they fail?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? A (sort of round-about) hint would be to consider the Chinese Remainder Theorem, if you've learned that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the residue class ring $R={\Bbb Z}_8$. The multiples of 4 form an ideal in $R$. Then $R/\langle 4\rangle$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb Z}_4$ which also has zero divisors.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $R=\mathbb Z_{12}$ and $I=\{\overline{0},\overline{6}\}$, then $R/I= \{\overline{0}+I,\overline{1}+I,\overline{2}+I,\overline{3}+I,\overline{4}+I,\overline{5}+I \} \cong \mathbb Z_6$ which has zero divisors, $(\overline{2}+I)(\overline{3}+I)=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you take a proper ideal $I$ of $R$ (a commutative ring) that is not prime, the quotient ring $R/I$ has nontrivial zero divisors.

Now take your favorite ring, for instance $\mathbb{Z}$; take two ideals $I$ and $J$ that are not prime and with $I\subsetneq J\subsetneq\mathbb{Z}$. Set $R=\mathbb{Z}/I$, so $R$ has zero divisors; take the ideal $J'=J/I$ in $R$ and note that $R/J'\cong R/J$ has zero divisors because $J$ is not prime.